# Get memory usage and execution time from a process initiated with the ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm working in a code executor in Java. The problem is how to control the execution time and memory usage of this execution.

I'm doing something like this:

```
public ExecutionResult execute(List<String> args, String inputFile) throws CommandLineExecutorException {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        if (inputFile != null) {
            builder.redirectInput(new File(inputFile));
        }

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int exitValue = process.exitValue();
        InputStream inputStream = exitValue == 0 ? process.getInputStream() : process.getErrorStream();
        String consoleOutput = readStream(inputStream);
        return new ExecutionResult(exitValue, consoleOutput, (endTime - startTime));
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new CommandLineExecutorException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to control the time of execution of the sub process. For the memory I'm still looking for the best option.

I used to use a script to control memory and time with linux commands when i was using php but I want to know if there is a better way to achive this in java.

Answer (score 1):

For monitoring child Java process you van use [Java JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/overview.html) to query various parameters of JVM process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552960/how-to-connect-to-a-java-program-on-localhost-jvm-using-jmx) for an example how to connect to remote JVM and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759831/how-do-i-access-memory-usage-programmatically-via-jmx) for retrieving memory info.

For monitoring non-Java processes you can use [SIGAR](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) multiplatform API.