# Run process from Java and watch its memory consumption

Tags: java, process, child-process

I'm writing a Java program that runs external executables using `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. This program should be able to watch running time and memory usage of a child process and terminate if it exceeds some predefined limits.

For time-based measurement it's pretty simple to achieve:

```
boolean inTime = process.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But I haven't found any methods for watching memory usage of a child process. Are there any ways to achieve this in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @gregwhitaker currently I'm using Windows. I suppose there aren't OS independent solutions to this kind of problems..

Answer (score 2):

> i don't know what you are asking exactly ,but if you are looking for how 
>     much memory your method will take while execution or runtime time

[Java Mission Control](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=381) read this

> you will find JFR and Mbeans right hand side after you open JMC(write "jmc" in terminal) and JFR will give you every single method name also it's child method name  as well as how much memory they are taking
>
> this is how you can check-::
>
> make a program with 3-4 methods , iterate them more than 5 lac so it will take so much time and you are able to watch what happening while execution
>
> now open flight recorder and go to (memory->Allocations-> Allocations in new tlab-> allocation Profile)
>
> hope you find your ans Here

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use local attach and fetch heap usage from the MemoryMXBean and the uptime from the RuntimeMXBean. See the class com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.

It's too much code to show, but you can look here

http://dontpanic.42.nl/2012/05/connecting-to-jvm-programmatically.html

for an example on how to list the virtual machines that are running, how to attach to them and start a management agent. Once you have a MBeanServerConnection you can do this:

```
MemoryMXBean memoryMBean = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(
                connection, new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Memory"), MemoryMXBean.class);
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMBean =     JMX.newMXBeanProxy(
                connection, new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Runtime"), RuntimeMXBean.class);
String pid = runtimeMBean.getName().split("@")[0];
long uptime = runtimeMBean.getUptime();
long memoryUsed = memoryMBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
```

You can then kill the process, for example like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill " + pid);
```

Comment: Does this work only if the target process (owner of pid) is also a Java process?

Comment: Yes, it must be a Java process.

Answer (score -1):

I hope below will help:
If your child process can send back details somehow I found this - 
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long usedMB = (rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024;
    logger.information(this, "memory usage" + usedMB);

in this thread; may be can help:
[How to monitor Java memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058991/how-to-monitor-java-memory-usage)

If you want to monitor from outside process this looks interesting - similar question I would say:
[Get memory usage and execution time from a process initiated with the ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616080/get-memory-usage-and-execution-time-from-a-process-initiated-with-the-processbui)

and in one answer someone is pointing to this link:
[How do I access memory usage programmatically via JMX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759831/how-do-i-access-memory-usage-programmatically-via-jmx)